# Refering to an Array. Incrementing and saving index

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Learning C through "Learning C the hard way", and doing some of my own exercises. I stumbled upon the following problem.

Let's say I have the following structure:

```
struct Person {
  char name[MAX_INPUT];
  int age;
}
```

In main(), I have declared the following array:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
  struct Person personList[MAX_SIZE];
  return 0;
}
```

Now let's say 2 functions away (main calls function1 which calls function2) I want to save a person inside the array I declared in the main function like so:

```
int function2(struct Person *list) {
  struct Person *prsn = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
  assert(prsn != NULL); // Why is this line necessary?

  // User input code goes here ... 

  // Now to save the Person created
  strcpy(prsn->name, nameInput);
  ctzn->age = ageInput;
  list = prsn; // list was passed by reference by function1, does main need to pass the array by
               // reference to function1 before?

  // This is where I get lost:
  // I want to increment the array's index, so next time this function is called and a 
  // new person needs to be saved, it is saved in the correct order in the array (next index)
}
```

So if I return to my main function and wanted to print the first three persons saved in it like so:

```
...
int i = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  printf("%s is %d old", personList[i].name, personList[i].age);
}
...
```

Basically how to reference the array across the application while keeping it persistent. Keeping in mind that main does not necessarily call the function directly that makes use of the array. I'm suspecting someone might suggesting declaring it as a global variable, then what would be the alternative? Double pointers? How do double pointers work?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: *// Why is this line necessary?* Because you're not guaranteed the memory.

Comment: `malloc()` attempts to give you the memory you request, if there is no memory to be given it will return `NULL`. You should look at the man page for malloc.

Comment: `list = prsn;` You likely wanted to pass a double pointer if you wanted to modify it.  This only modifies the local `list` variable.  The caller of this function will never know that the passed pointer was modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few pointers (no pun intended!) to help you along:

1. As it stands, the line `struct Person personList[MAX_SIZE];` allocates memory for `MAX_SIZE` number of `Person` structs.  You don't actually need to allocate more memory using `malloc` if this is what you are doing.
2. However, you could save some memory by only allocating memory when you actually need a person.  In this case, you want the `personList` array to contain *pointers* to `Person` structs, not the structs themselves (which you create using `malloc`).

   That is: `struct Person * personList[MAX_SIZE];`

   When you create the person:

   `struct Person * person = (struct Person *) malloc(sizeof(struct Person));`

   `personList[index] = person;`

   And when you use the person list: `printf("%s", personList[index]->name);`
3. Arrays don't magically keep a record of any special index.  You have to do this yourself.  One way is to always pass the length of the array to each function that needs it.

   `void function1(struct Person * personList, int count);`

   If you wanted to modify the count variable when you returned back to the calling function, you could pass it by reference:

   `void function1(struct Person * personList, int * count);`

   A possibly more robust way would be to encapsulate the count and the array together into another structure.

   `struct PersonList { struct Person * list[MAX_SIZE]; int count; }`

   This way you can write a set of functions that always deal with the list data coherently -- whenever you add a new person, you always increment the count, and so on.

   `int addNewPerson(struct PersonList * personList, char * name, int age);`

I think that much should be helpful to you.  Just leave a comment if you would like something to be explained in more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation.This line here is actually exactly what I am trying to do:

`void function1(struct Person * personList, int * count);`

But a quick one, say from function1 I want to pass these same references to function2, would I need to use double pointers.

Comment: @user1202888 no you don't need to use double pointers in this situation.  You can just pass the `personList` pointer through to the next function - as long as you haven't modified its value the other function will see the same array.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, malloc does not guarantee to allocate new space from the memory and return it. If it cannot allocate the requested memory, it returns a NULL value. That's why it is necessary to check the pointer.

While you are calling function two, you can pass the address of the next element by using a variable that holds the current count of the array in function1;

function2(&personList[count++]);

then you return the current count from function1 to the main function;

int size=function1(personList);

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about the assertion. I will try to use a count variable and keep passing it around my program by reference.